# (Amazon Mechanical Turk) Is it possible to place multiple crowdforms in 1 HIT?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am trying to create HITs as a requester for relevancy check: ie have the worker select how relevant given data1 is to given data2. I would like to ask in a set of 3 relevancy checks because there are 3 of data2 for each data1. I remember seeing a blog post (which I can't find anymore) that said as long as I concatenate multiple crowdforms in 1, it'll only allow the worker to submit once all answers are entered, but during the trial run, it accepted responses that only selected 1 answer. How would I go about making sure that the worker selected an answer for all 3 questions before submitting? (Unnecessary information has been removed)

```
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>


<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

    <crowd-classifier 

      categories="['Very Relevant', 'Relevant', 'Somewhat Relevant', 'Not relevant']"

    >

      <classification-target>

...

      </classification-target>


</crowd-form>      



<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

    <crowd-classifier 

      categories="['Very Relevant', 'Relevant', 'Somewhat Relevant', 'Not relevant']"

    >

      <classification-target>
...

      </classification-target>




      
</crowd-form>
```